# How do I feed the locals?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I DON'T CARE WHAT THE SIGN SAYS!! It's cute and I need to stuff food in its.... wherever that species traditionally stuffs food!

The internet told me that I can feed the little critters that I've discovered. Is this an ability that you get later on, or is it something that I can do on my starting planet? How do I do it and what benefits do I potentially get from it?

Comment: +1 because feeding animals despite what the sign says deserves +10 but I can only give +1, stupid system...

Comment: Still wating for the release on PC since I don't own a PS4 but most streamers I've watched just walked up to the face of the creature and pressed square (no clue about what to feed tho... Probably not iron or gold)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I only played for a few minutes, but I was able to feed Carbon to the critters on my planet, Dickbuttia, by simply walking up to them and pressing 'square' when prompted.

Comment: I've tested this and it is correct! The real problem is getting them to stand still for the Carbon->"Mouth" interaction...

Comment: Most interactive activities can be performed on the move... I've chased things down while feeding them. Be persistent.

Answer (score 4):

On PC: If you can get close enough to fauna without them running away, you get a blue HUD overlay prompting you to press and hold 'E' - this effectively initiates offering food to the animal. Once successful, you will then be presented with a white prompt to actually feed it, assuming you have the materials the animal eats, again by pressing and holding 'E'. From what I gather, this translates to the square button on the PS4 version.

I have had to chase after some animals while holding down 'E' the first time, which has proven effective on skittish fauna. Once the first 'E' is complete, they stop running and the second 'E' has been much easier.

Comment: Is there any benefit to the player?

Comment: I can't be positive yet, but I think that, in the same way that killing animals will get the attention of sentinels in a bad way, feeding animals will increase your positive standing. The animals you feed also feature a smiley face icon above their heads, so you got that going for you, which is nice...

Comment: For some critters, after feeding them and waiting a little bit, they will, hrmm, well... poop, for lack of a better term, a substance you can collect. One species transformed carbon into zinc that way.